# Get Images From iCloud account to Android App Programmatically

Tags: android, icloud

**May be this is duplicate question but I need solution for my requirement.**

I have searched so much but I am not able to get any idea for this as how to implement or what logic should I use for my requirement.

**Requirement:**

I just want to allow users to login with their iCloud account from my application and get data as backup like images, audio etc.

**So please help me for this. Any help appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

This is called webScraping , Basically, it's getting some data from a website from it's source code assuming that you can understand HTML & CSS Selectors to get exactly what you want

Use. [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) or [htmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) or [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) , they will provide passing login forms and then, scrape the data you want.

NOTE: You will need to cache the images if you are using GridView or ListView because getView() will set them everytime and this will make your app the slowest app ever.